# jquery validate error message does not disappear when checkbox clicked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, jquery-validate

I have a form And I am trying to validate this with jQuery. I am using jQUery validation and jquery (from [here](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/) ). Now it validates everything. However, at the places I am using custom checkbox using pretty checkable (custom9-11), it does validate. I have the following the ignore

```
  $('#submitDetails').validate({
    ignore:' ',
```

However, when I click the checkbox again, the error message does not dissapear. Basically when one clicks the submit button the error message for the checkbox appears. ANd when I click the checkbox, the error message does not disappear as expected

To call prettycheckable I am calling

```
$().ready(function () {
  $('input.myClass').prettyCheckable();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is because the validation plugin listens to the click event for validation and the styling plugin is firing it... it is firing only the change event

Add a handler like

```
$('#custom9').on('change', function(){ 
    $(this).valid() 
})
```

Comment: @Himu what about the previous question's answer

Comment: Hi 
It is not 100% working. Please  follow the following steps to reproduce the issue 1) Click on link http://staging.serviceportal.com.au/service05/plush_form.do 2) Click on submit button at the bottom 3) Click on the red error message after the checkbox (do not click the checkbox or the label of the checkbox). The error message disseapears . Now if you click the checkbox, the error message reappears whereas it should not. ???